# Does laravel scope works for every model instance?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.7
and PHP 7.2.10.

I want those records, for which either max_age = 0 or if max_age > 0, then it should check if given `$age` is in between `max_age` and `min_age`.

In `CarPremium` model

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
 {
     if ( $this->max_age == 0 ) {
        return $query;
     } else {
       return $query->where('min_age', '<=', $age)->where('max_age', '>=', $age)->orWhere('max_age','=',0);
    }
}
```

I am getting the records for which age not between `max_age` and `min_age` and not getting records for which `max_age = 0`.

In tinker

```
>>> App\Models\CarPremium::query()->age(18)->get()
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3064
     all: [
       App\Models\CarPremium {#3063
         id: 2,
         min_age: 25,
         max_age: 100,
         status: 1,
         created_at: "2018-12-10 05:34:39",
         updated_at: "2018-12-10 05:34:39",
       },
       App\Models\CarPremium {#3064
         id: 8,
         min_age: 18,
         max_age: 30,
         status: 1,
         created_at: "2018-12-10 05:34:39",
         updated_at: "2019-01-15 09:14:53",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Comment: Is it necessary to call `query()`?

Comment: @ManzurulHoqueRumi is there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update scope with :

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
{

    return $query->where('max_age','=',0)
        ->orWhere(function($q) use($age){
            return $q->where('min_age', '<=', $age)->where('max_age', '>=', $age);
        });

}
```

Then you can do :

`App\Models\CarPremium::age(18)->get()`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use model properties (`$this->max_age`) in a scoped function. The query has not yet been executed so it's impossible to compare to a local value.

A better way would be to add an `or where` to your query:

```
public function scopeAge($query, $age)
{
    return $query
            ->where('max_age', 0)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($age) {
                $query  
                    ->where('min_age', '<=', $age)
                    ->where('max_age', '>=', $age);
            });
}
```